# Variable declaration

Tags: solidity, blockchain, remix, compiler, declaration

I am new to solidity.Below is the snippet of solidity source code which I came across :-

```
    pragma solidity ^0.5.1;

library SafeMath { 
    function sub(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
      assert(b <= a); //error handling condition
      return a - b;
    }

    function add(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
      uint256 c = a + b;
     
      return c;
    }
}

contract SmartContract {          
   

    event Approval(address indexed tokenOwner, address indexed spender, uint tokens);
    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint tokens);

    modifier onlyOwner  {
        require (msg.sender == ownerCon);
        _;
    }
    
    mapping(address => uint256) balances;  
    

    uint256 totalSupply_;
    address ownerCon;
    using SafeMath for uint256;
    string public constant name = "SmartCoin"; 
    string public constant symbol = "SC"; 
    uint8 public constant decimals = 18;     

// some more functions

    }
```

Here  all the entire variable declaration was not done in the beginning as what we do in C++ , but rather in the middle of programme. I want to know that whether this Smart contract will work properly or not. And if it will , then how the compiler will compile the source code given that it encounters few functions even before those variables have been declared .

Answer (score 0):

the compiler has an expected layout for the order in which the code is laid out

Layout contract elements in the following order:

1. Pragma statements
2. Import statements
3. Interfaces
4. Libraries
5. Contracts

Inside each contract, library or interface, use the following order:

1. Type declarations
2. State variables
3. Events Modifiers
4. Functions

At a quick glance, that contract should compile. Please check out this link for more info on the code layout:

https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.14/style-guide.html